# Using the phone's accelerometer and microphone to measure vibration

Tags: android, accelerometer, microphone, measure, vibration

I am making an Android app that will measure the vibration when the phone is put on the floor. How do I use the accelerometer (for 0-50Hz) and microphone (for 50-500Hz) to measure the vibration? I am new to Android development but this is a project given to me. I know that there are a lot of apps related to this in the appstore but I have no idea how it is made. I searched for tutorials but I only found a tutorial concerning shake gestures.

Answer (score 1):

First implement a listener for Accelerometer:

```
class SENSOR_EVENT_LISTENER implements SensorEventListener {
    float[] accelerometer_data = new float[3];
    float[] gravity = new float[3];

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {

            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                final float alpha = 0.8f;

                // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
                gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
                gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
                gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

                accelerometer_data[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
                accelerometer_data[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
                accelerometer_data[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
                break;

            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

Then register your receiver:

```
final SensorManager sensor_manager = (SensorManager) m_context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
listener = new SENSOR_EVENT_LISTENER();

final List<Sensor> sensors = sensor_manager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

if(sensors.size() > 0) {
    sensor = sensor_manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensor_manager.registerListener(listener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
```

Check values before vibration and during the vibration. You will see there's a remarkable change in the values during the vibration.

I'm not sure about microphone but listening accelerometer alone will be enough for you to measure vibration. I can update my code if you need help with microphone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you also include microphone? Also, how can I use the accelerometer data (x,y,z) to find the vibration frequency? Do I use Fast Fourier transform or what

Comment: On a stable surface as the device is standing still, accelerometer values change in a smaller interval and have smaller peaks. While the device is vibrating, you will notice that the absolute peak values are way more higher. Thats how you can detect vibration. For the mic code ill need time to implement it

Comment: I've been researching and I can't really grasp the concepts about accelerometers, frequencies, and noise levels (dB). Yes, I need dB and Hz. I need to make a graph, y-axis for dB and x-axis for Hz.

Comment: Check the [MotionSensor](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) docs, you will get the idea. But i'm not sure if you are able to get that detailed information. You might have to calculate the db and Hz on your own depending on the value you read.

Comment: So have you implemented the microphone? I'm also researching about it.

Answer (score 0):

using the phone's microphone, you can stimulate the phone's vibration system. There is a watt of sound. The vibration also vibrates at a low volume.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).